# Is the use of the word `synchronized` contrary to its meaning in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

This is from a beginner java learner: If synchronize means to "cause to occur or operate at the same time or rate.", the use of word synchronized in java in its current fashion seems contrary to its meaning: those "synchronized" can not take place at the same exact moment due to  blocks. I gather perhaps its use reflects more on the purpose which is to be able to run multiple threads at the same time frame.

Comment: Synchronized, computing: "_cause (a set of data or files) to remain identical in more than one location_" or "_coordinate; combine_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. The "if" premise of your syllogism is not true. @Boris the Spider gave the correct definition of "synchronized", which is entirely consistent with Java's use of the term. But more importantly, when a term of art is used in Java, the definition that matters isn't the one from an English dictionary, but the one from the Java Language Specification (JLS). How does the JLS define the term?